Error de typeError con testeo en Vitest
Tengo un problema, estoy intentando realizar algo simple usando TDD para ir armando el proyecto, el tema esta en que la documentacion en vitest [1]: https://vitest.dev/api/mock.html#mockimplementation
me indica que yo tengo que importar {vi} de 'vitest' y ahi puedo simular funciones usando const fn = vi.fn(). Hasta ahi bien, no? ahora esta en que me dice que "fn" no es una funcion, no entiendo el por qué si es literalmente como se define en la documentacion, ademas de que al ir escribiendo codigo me sale como opcion el vi.fn()
import { cleanup, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { afterEach, beforeEach, describe, expect, test, vi } from "vitest";


const useValueInput = vi.fn().mockImplementation((newValue) => {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState('0');

  const refreshValue = () => {
    // No olvidar agregar un 'event' como parametro y 'event.target.value' para su gestion. Esto es solo testeo.
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  return { value, refreshValue };
});

const InputValue = vi.fn().mockImplementationOnce( ( handleChange, value ) => {
  return(
    <>
      <input type='text' pattern='[0-9+\-*/]*' onChange={handleChange} value={value} placeholder='0'/>;
      <div>{`Resultado esperado en pantalla: ${value}`}</div>
    </>
  );
});

describe('input - sin teclado', () => {
  beforeEach(cleanup());
  afterEach(
    vi.clearAllMocks(),
  );

  test.skip('Deberia renderizar correctamente', () => {
    render(<></>);
  });

  test('Deberia renderizar un input que ingrese solo numeros', () => {
    const { value, refreshValue } = useValueInput.mockReturnValue('12');

      render(<InputValue handleChange={refreshValue} value={value} />);
      expect( value ).toBeTypeOf('string');
  });

});

